# Использование ajax запроса для добавления данных в БД

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Пытаюсь добавить данные в таблицу book. Использую для этого ajax запрос. Но почему то когда выполняю страницу, смотрю код клиента а там попросту нет ajax запроса.
Вот мой код:
Контроллер:

```
Context db = new Context();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Book> books = db.Books.ToList();
            List<User> users = db.Users.ToList();
            ViewBag.Users = users;

            return View(books);
        }

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Book book)
    {
        db.Books.Add(book);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.Users = db.Users.ToList();

        return View(db.Books.ToList());
    }
```

Стартовое view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

@model IEnumerable<AjaxTest.Models.Book>

<h2>Каталог книг</h2>

<input type="submit" value="Добавить" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mod" />

@Html.Partial("ModalCreate")

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table" table-bordered>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Название</th>
                    <th>Автор</th>
                    <th>Цена</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Author)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Price)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>

<h2>Список пользователей</h2>

<body>
    <div>
        <table class="table" table-bordered>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Имя</th>
                    <th>Фамилия</th>
                    <th>Возраст</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in ViewBag.Users as List<AjaxTest.Models.User>)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Surname)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.Age)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

View модального окна:

```
<div id="mod" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Новая книга</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Название</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtName" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Автор</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtAuthor" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><p>Цена</p></td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="txtPrice" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Закрыть</button>
                <button id="btnAdd" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnAdd').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/Index",
                data: {
                    "Name": $('#txtName').val(),
                    "Author": $('#txtAuthor').val(),
                    "Price": $('#txtPrice').val()
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    }
```

У меня такое подозрение что нужно javascript секцию вынести на стартовую вью, так как модалка вызывается там как partial. А так как сейчас это можно сделать? Или вообще подскажите как нужно сделать то что я описал.

И есть второй ещё вопрос.
Вот выполняется у меня этот запрос если перетащить javascript в основную вью(первый вопрос не отменяется, хочу понять), но таблица не обновляется, нужно обновить страницу вручную что бы увидеть результат, как сделать так что бы таблица обновлиась? Может как то нужно результат ajax запроса куда то положить, чего я не делаю.

Comment: А у вас 2 сабмит кнопки, но нет формы, так и задумано?

Comment: @tym32167 первую кнопку не обязательно впринципе сабмит, ту которая вызвает модальное окно.

Comment: @tym32167 я сейчас просто не понимаю почему javascript код не видно из модального окна, но я попробовал перетащить javascript на основную вью тогда код видно и кнопка работает.